# Design, Authentication and Authorization strategy needed for a Spring MVC application using Spring Security

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am learning Spring-MVC and Spring-security. I decided to create a project in which I can practice the concepts. What I need help in is coming up with a strategy for authorizing and Authenticating my users. Any examples you can reference or ideas you can provide me would be very helpful for my design.

Application Synopsis:

> The application will allow users to create artwork on like an HTML5
>   canvas and share it with the world. People can comment on the artwork
>   if they have the permalink to it and are authorized to see it. The
>   creator of the artwork allows this art to either be public or password
>   secured.

Here is the usage workflow:

> User logs in 
>   -> is directed to their profile page containing list of
>   several artworks 
>  -> User can choose to edit or delete an existing art. 
>  ->
>   User can also create a new art. 
> Each artwork should have a permalink that the 
>   user can share with the world by making it public or password protected/public.

I am not sure where to begin designing this thing as I am a rookie. Can someone provide advice on how to handle this use-case in terms of designing/architecting this application?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the requirements I can see not much of Spring Security design, this can be easily managed with more or less basic Spring Security configuration.
For authentication part I would go with implementing UserDetails and UserDetailsService interfaces, i.e. creating custom authentication provider. UserDetails covers domain model logic representing Spring Security-aware entity on this layer. This is usually combined with application User entity, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APP_USER")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="IS_ACTIVE", nullable=false)
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Column(name="USERNAME", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD", nullable=false)
    private String password;

    …

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isActive;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return isActive;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return isActive;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return isActive;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Notice a number of overridden methods, this is a consequence of implementing UserDetails and required for authentication to work properly.

UserDetailsService resides on a service layer and represents Spring Security-compatible implementation of authentication provider which works with UserDetails objects:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {
    …

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        return userDao.getUserByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Here too you are free to combine it with your services, for instance working with application user entity. The example implies using DAO to fetch UserDetails objects which depends on your persistence framework.

Regarding protecting the images with passwords I would not go with Spring Security for this since for me it sounds more like a functional requirement rather than security one.